# Hide xaxis hoverinfo in python plotly go

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

When I set `hovermode = 'x'` it shows a little black box denoting where on the x-axis my tooltip is coming from. I'd like to remove this little black box. Seen below is the little black box with a red arrow pointing to it - I want to remove this.

[image: IMAGE: xaxis-black box]

I looked at [a javascript solution](https://community.plotly.com/t/disable-x-axis-hover-text/28970) but wasn't able to successfully apply it to the python version that I'm using. Using inspect element, I was able to isolate the black box. If there's a css solution that could get rid of it, that would work as well, however is unideal.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.